# Formula for this pattern

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I am trying to develop a computer program to compute the tax for a given base salary, I believe given the format of the income tax table that I have there should be a formula to calculate the tax for a given base salary.  Below is the sample format of income tax table.

```
 Annual Salary   Monthly From    Ranges To   Tax Due
 18,000.00       0.00            1,500.00    0.00
 18,060.00       1,500.01        1,505.00    0.25 
 18,120.00       1,505.01        1,510.00    0.50 
 18,180.00       1,510.01        1,515.00    0.75 
 18,240.00       1,515.01        1,520.00    1.00 
 18,300.00       1,520.01        1,525.00    1.25 
 18,360.00       1,525.01        1,530.00    1.50
```

As you can see for every range of salary there is an increment of .25 on tax. I have tried to find my own formula but I could not find an accurate one.

Comment: If I make $18060$ a year, do I get taxed $0$ on the first $18000$ and $0.25$ on the rest, or do I get taxed $0.25$ on the whole amount?

Comment: You get 0.25 on that amount.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming, and should go to stackoverflow.

Comment: You have a piecewise defined function, your best (only?) bet is to do it piecewise, i.e., a cascade of `if` or a table like the above, where you can search for (the beginning) of the range and get the tax rate. I'd vote for the table, as it is easier to change if something changes. But this has little to do with math, so I'm voting to close. Perhaps this should go to stackoverflow?

Comment: @vonbrad you are entitled to your opinion, but I think its not about programming yet. I have to program the formula. Getting the formula then not knowing how to program the formula should lead me to stackoverflow.

Comment: @vonbrand:  there is enough regularity here (assuming the pattern continues) to make it an expression instead of a table lookup. I think the question was posed more in terms of math than programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tax is $0.25$ on every $5.00$ or portion above $1500$.  So you can use $\lceil \frac {\text{monthly}-1500} 5 \rceil \cdot 0.25$

Comment: Millikah thank you, I tested this for the last line but its gave me 1.25 instead of 1.50. But I think it's very close.

Comment: Did you round up to the next whole number?  For the last line, the brackets should give you $6$

Comment: I did this (1525.01-1500)/5 = 25.01/5 = Ceil(5.002) = 5 not 6.

Comment: No, ceiling of 5.002 is 6.  Anything at all larger than 5 rounds up to 6 when taking the ceiling.

Comment: Great, that solved the problem. Anyway will the same formula work if the tax increase from 0.25 to 0.50 for every 5.00 at some point in the middle.

Comment: If there is another breakpoint, you will need two formulas, one below and one above.  The same style of formula may work, depending on the regularity of the schedule.  As vonbrand suggested, eventually you need a lookup table.